# Variable from string interpolation returns a non unit value

Tags: variables, less, interpolation, units-of-measurement

This is the first time I'mn building a site using LESS and encountered a problem best described by the code below:

```
@section-row-padding-size-xs: 30px;
@section-row-padding-size-sm: 50px;
@section-row-padding-size-md: 100px;
@section-row-padding-size-lg: 140px;

.section-row-padding( @size ) {
    @padding-size: ~"@{section-row-padding-size-@{size}}";

    .section-row {
        padding: @padding-size 0;

        &.quarter-padding-top {
            padding-top: @padding-size * 0.25;
        }

        &.quarter-padding-bottom {
                padding-bottom: @padding-size * 0.25;
        }

        &.half-padding-top {
            padding-top: @padding-size * 0.5;
        }

        &.half-padding-bottom {
            padding-bottom: @padding-size * 0.5;
        }

        &.three-quarters-padding-top {
            padding-top: @padding-size * 0.75;
        }

        &.three-quarters-padding-bottom {
            padding-bottom: @padding-size * 0.75;
        }
    }
}
```

All this code does is outputting the right padding sizes for use in media queries.

Any call to `.section-row-padding()` either with lg, md, sm and xs argument should output the appropriate padding sizes.

The problem is caused by the @padding-size not intepreted as a px unit but rather as a string. I've tried several interpolation methods, but none of them works.
`isnumber( @padding-size )` outputs false and `istring( @padding-size )` outputs true.
`@padding-size + 0px` does not work either, it says Operation on an invalid type.

Is there anything that I missed?

Thanks for your time and answer!

Comment: `padding: @padding-size 0;` does work but any math operations fails.

Comment: Why don't you just pass the variable into the mixin? .section-row-padding(@section-row-padding-size-xs);

Comment: That's true! Silly me, I was using another mixins for defining heading sizes from h1 to h3, and this method was more convenient but I didn't thought about that simpler way.

But still, I want to know how to fix the problem above :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nested interpolation i.e. `~"@{section-row-padding-size-@{size}}"` is not officially supported in Less. (It works in current versions but may stop to work at any moment eventually).

The correct method to achieve what you want is:

```
.section-row-padding(@size) {
    @var-name: "section-row-padding-size-@{size}";
    @padding-size: @@var-name;
    padding: (@padding-size * 2);
}
```

or shorter:

```
.section-row-padding(@size) {
    @padding-size: "section-row-padding-size-@{size}";
    padding: (@@padding-size * 2);
}
```

See ["variable references"](http://lesscss.org/features/#variables-feature-variable-names) for `@@` meaning.

> The problem is caused by the `@padding-size` not interpreted as a px unit but rather as a string.

Exactly. Using `~""` is like saying to the compiler "do not interpreter this value, it's just some string with whatever value I want you to pass through". Thus the type of the value returned by `~"@{section-row-padding-size-@{size}}"` in your example is not a number and it can't be used with arithmetic operations (hence: "Operation on an invalid type").

(A few links for "why `~""` should be avoided whenever possible": [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21010520), [2](https://github.com/less/less.js/issues/1790), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14384803/2712740), [4](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14901154/2712740) etc.).

Comment: I made a "whenever possible" remark :) If it is unavoidable then it's unavoidable (hense why it still exists at all) E.g. in my example it is OK since later the `@@` statement makes the compiler to interpreter the "unknown" escaped string as a variable name and it all goes safe.

Comment: Okay, got it. In the end I didn't use the ~"" and it still works, Thank you!

Comment: Indeed, I actually forgot that *just* string w/o any `~` also works with `@@` :). I guess I need to update my example.