# Less CSS fade function not working with variable

Tags: css, less

i'm using Less CSS with bundler, which I build on an Asp.Net platform.

I have the following code:

```
&::after {
    .ScaleX(0);
    .Transition(0.2s 0.2s);
    background-color: fade(@accentColor, 12%);
    border-radius:0.2rem;
    height:100%;
    top:0;
    z-index:-1;
}
```

It fails to complile.

If I change the background-color like this, it works:

```
background-color:@accentColor;
```

I set my color palettes like this:

```
.AccentPalette(orange);

.AccentPalette(@palette; @color:500) {
    .Swatch(@palette); 

    @accentColor:~"@{accent@{color}}";

    @accent50:  @50;
    ... and some more
}

.Swatch(orange)
{
    @50: #fff3e0;
    @100:#ffe0b2;
    @200:#ffcc80;
    @300:#ffb74d;
    @400:#ffa726;
    @500:#ff9800;
    @600:#fb8c00;
    @700:#f57c00;
    @800:#ef6c00;
    @900:#e65100;
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I had answered the question without realizing it was a dupe (it was a very old one) and so have closed it now. The questions are in essence the same as both are referring to color functions on an evaluated string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It fails to compile because the `@accentColor` variable seems to contain a String and not a Color as its value. The [`fade()`](http://lesscss.org/functions/#color-operations-fade) function only works on color values.

To fix the problem, convert the String into the Color value by using the [`color()`](http://lesscss.org/functions/#misc-functions-color) function.

```
background-color: fade(color(@accentColor), 12%);
```

---

The value is being considered as a String because of the below interpolation statement. The [`e()` or the `~"value"`](http://lesscss.org/functions/#string-functions-e) function outputs a String.

```
@accentColor: ~"@{accent@{color}}";
```

---

As pointed out by seven-phases-max in his comment, the below approach would also avoid the need for the `color()` function.

```
.AccentPalette(@palette; @color:500) {
  .Swatch(@palette); 
  @accentColor: "accent@{color}"; /* note the change, we are just concatenating and not evaluating */
  @accent500:  @500;

  &::after {
    background-color: fade(@@accentColor, 12%); /* actual evaluation happens here */
    border-radius:0.2rem;
    height:100%;
    top:0;
    z-index:-1;
  }  
}
```

Comment: Harry, you're an absolute star!

Comment: I liked the [previous version](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24492770) more. The fact that now we can convert a string to a color still does not make all that `~"@{a@{b}}"` anything but a misuse.

Comment: @seven-phases-max: Ah, a duplicate answer :( Let me close this one and thanks for finding that one. I agree that one seems better.

Comment: I did not raise the duplicate mark as since those times two key things have changed (that days `~"@{a@{b}}"` syntax was not even officially supported and `color()` could not actually convert all types of strings as does now). So it's up to you, but yes, probably adding more info to the older answer would be more convenient).

Comment: @seven-phases-max: That's true but as you say it might be better to maintain one copy - the old one. It already has the color() function mentioned but is using complex JS stuff so will update that also :)